# Place ColVis in to a custom div position from datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using this plugin and method for datatables ColVis http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/ColVis/style.html

How can I place the ColVis drop down into a custom div positioned anywhere on the page. Outside the sDom?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the fnInitComplete callback function for DataTables and then simply move the element to wherever you want in the DOM using standard jQuery or DOM methods.

It is also possible to create a new ColVis instance using "new ColVis( oDTSettings, init );", but I suspect the first option is probably easier :-).

Allan